# RESTfull client for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, sinatra

I'd like to develop a REST client in ruby that can talk with a Rails service. Is there any framework that I can use easily get started without recoding from the ground up. I'm looking something like "sinatra" but for the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Satya says, [rest-client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) is very nice. But since you specifically mention sinatra as a reference point, i think [faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday) is worth a look.

Comment: and what about Active Resource ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the RestClient gem. It's pretty much what you're asking for. Of course, it's a library, not a framework.